# Apache Poi - Excel cell with numbers seperated by comma are converted to decimal number

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

When considering the following example:
[image: excel cell content]

A3: is the easiest example. The cell contains a list of values seperated by comma 
A2: is a decimal number written with a point
but
A1: is a list of 2 values: value one and value two. But when these values are read by the Apache Poi they are always converted to a number. The value coming from that cell is always 1.2.
The goal is actually to maintain the comma in such cases, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve this using the Apache Poi interface:

The code that I use to read the Excel
Note: i have also tried doing it with the cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC and CellType.STRING, but those also did not have the required result

```
try {
        FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(xlsxFile);

        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);

        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        ...

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            String[] rowData = new String[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
                if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                    rowData[i] = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
                }
                else {
                    rowData[i] = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                }
            }

            data.add(rowData);
        }
```

these are the settings for the seperators in my Excel: [excel settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HpIS.png)

Comment: Are they really commas? Or is it a number with a formatting locale applied, for a locale that uses `,` instead of `.` for a decimal place?

Comment: I did no formatting to the cells. The formatting was done automatically for the cells. A1 has the GENERAL cell format.I also added an extra image to the question. The system seperators for excel (decimal = point, thousands = comma)

Comment: If you open the file on a computer with a Locale set to US-English, what displays for the problem cells? I suspect the `,` may have become a `.`, but as I don't have your file, you'll have to check for us....

Comment: The thing is, the code should work for both systems. Whether there is a `.`or a `,` used. It should be independent from the Locale Set.

Comment: @Gagravarr can you help me further with this?

Comment: Excel files are always stored in US-English locale, anything else is done in the client at runtime. You can ask Apache POI to render some things (but not all) in an alternate locale, but it looks like that's the source of your confusion